# Tooltips on filtered rows in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, rowfilter

I have a JTable and any single row in it has associated a different tooltip when mouse hover a row.  I have created a "filter" for this table; when it is applied it perfectly hides the rows need to be hidden but when I hover the mouse on the filtered rows, looks like the tooltip is referring to the row that occupied the same row position of the new current row.

For example:

Table

ROW 1 -> tooltip 1

ROW 2 -> tooltip 2

Apply Filter to Table:

ROW 2 -> tooltip 1

So ROW 2 is displaying the tooltip 1 instead of 2.

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = (TableRowSorter<TableModel>) table.getRowSorter();
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
```

My table that extends JTable has:

```
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
    final int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    TableModel model = getModel();
    // take the value from the first column of the selected row
    String tip = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0));
    return tip;
}
```

So it looks like using the model is not (quite obvious) updated respect to the filter.  I tried using TableModel model = getRowSorter().getModel() too but without any luck.

How can I point to a correct "filtered model" to retrieve the correct row position?

UPDATE:

I have replaced the "rowIndex" code like this:

```
final int rowIndex = convertRowIndexToModel(rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()));
```

It partially solves the problem, but when some rows are added dynamically to the table with the filter applied and I hover new rows I get the exception (with relative API description):

IndexOutOfBoundsException -> if sorting is enabled and passed an index outside the range of the JTable as determined by the method getRowCount

Comment: works no issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), there must be another issue

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the views row index to the model's row index

Have a look at [JTable#convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. It almost solves the problem tho I have still some issue with it.  Please see the update above.

Comment: Make sure that you're not updating the table model out side of the Event Dispatching Thread, this will cripple the sorter/filter

Answer (score 2):

You should not override that `JTable#getToolTipText` method. Just set the tooltip-text on the component returned by your renderer. The `JTable` will pick it up automatically. You can see this in the implementation of the `getTooltipText` method of the `JTable`